# rename file.jpg.jpg to file.jpg using powershell

Tags: powershell

I inadvertently named over a thousand files as `filename.jpg.jpg`.  My desired end state is to have the file name as `filename.jpg`.  How can I use PowerShell to fix this?

I have tried many examples from blogs and find that the first `.jpg` is apparently being seen as the file extension. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as my only alternative is to manually rename all the files.

Comment: Hello, any bash solution is good for you ? All files .jpg.jpg are in the same directory ?

Comment: @AdrienLeber PowerShell implies Windows, which doesn't come with bash.

Comment: Ok, deleted my answer. Thank you Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Get-childItem constant* | % {rename-item $_.name ($_.name -replace '.jpg.jpg','.jpg')}
```

it will replace .jpg.jpg to .jpg

Comment: This also has the potential to match other things like sjpg1jpg.... You should escape your periods if you are using regex or at least be aware of the risk.

Comment: And the `name` property only works if the working directory is the same as the file to rename.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to retrieve the files and prefilter it using the `-Filter` parameter.

You should use the `FullName` property instead of the `Name` for the [Rename-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) cmdlet whenever your *working directory* is a diffrent one.

The `regex`I use here escapes the periods (mentioned by Matt) and also ensures to match the end of the filename (`$`).

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'YOUR_PATH_HERE' -Filter '*.jpg.jpg' | 
    foreach { Rename-Item $_.FullName ($_.FullName-replace '\.jpg\.jpg$','.jpg') }
```

**Note**: If you need to *recursively* rename the files, you just need to add `-recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem`cmdlet.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'YOUR_PATH_HERE' -Filter '*.jpg.jpg' | Rename-Item  -NewName {$_.FullName-replace '\.jpg\.jpg$','.jpg'}` should also work

Comment: *cough* don't answer gimmie the codes questions *cough*